# How migrate mybatis mapper from Java to Kotlin in spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have spring-boot application with MyBatis ORM. In java I write like

```
@Mapper
@Repository
public interface FooMapper {

    @SelectProvider(type = SqlProviderAdapter.class, method = "select")
    @Results(id = "resultFoo", value = {
            @Result(property = "rowId", column = "ROW_ID"),
            @Result(property = "created", column = "CREATED"),
            @Result(property = "lastUpdated", column = "LAST_UPD"),
            @Result(property = "fooId", column = "FOO_ID"),
    })
    Foo findBy(SelectStatementProvider selectStatement);

    @SelectProvider(type = SqlProviderAdapter.class, method = "select")
    @Results(value = {
            @Result(property = "rowId", column = "ROW_ID"),
            @Result(property = "created", column = "CREATED"),
            @Result(property = "lastUpdated", column = "LAST_UPD"),
            @Result(property = "fooId", column = "FOO_ID"),
    })
    List<Foo> findListBy(SelectStatementProvider selectStatement);

    @SelectProvider(type = SqlProviderAdapter.class, method = "select")
    @Results(value = {
            @Result(property = "fooId", column = "FOO_ID")
    })
    List<String> findFooListBy(SelectStatementProvider selectStatement);

    @InsertProvider(type = SqlProviderAdapter.class, method = "insert")
    @Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "record.rowId", keyColumn = "row_id")
    int insert(InsertStatementProvider<Foo> insertStatement);

    @UpdateProvider(type = SqlProviderAdapter.class, method = "update")
    int update(UpdateStatementProvider updateStatement);
}
```

This works great!

But I need to convert all my application to Kotlin.
I tried the following code:

```
@Mapper
@Repository
interface FooMapper {
    @SelectProvider(type = SqlProviderAdapter::class, method = "select")
    @Results(
        id = "resultReferralActivation",
        value = [Result(property = "rowId", column = "ROW_ID"), Result(
            property = "created",
            column = "CREATED"
        ), Result(property = "lastUpdated", column = "LAST_UPD"), Result(
            property = "fooId",
            column = "FOO_ID"
        )]
    )
    fun findBy(selectStatement: SelectStatementProvider?): Foo?

    @SelectProvider(type = SqlProviderAdapter::class, method = "select")
    @Results(
        value = [Result(property = "rowId", column = "ROW_ID"), Result(
            property = "created",
            column = "CREATED"
        ), Result(property = "lastUpdated", column = "LAST_UPD"), Result(
            property = "fooId",
            column = "FOO_ID"
        )]
    )
    fun findListBy(selectStatement: SelectStatementProvider?): List<Foo?>?

    @SelectProvider(type = SqlProviderAdapter::class, method = "select")
    @Results(value = [Result(property = "fooId", column = "FOO_ID")])
    fun findFooListBy(selectStatement: InsertStatementProvider?): List<String?>?

    @InsertProvider(type = SqlProviderAdapter::class, method = "insert")
    @Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "record.rowId", keyColumn = "row_id")
    fun insert(insertStatement: InsertStatementProvider<Foo?>?): Int

    @UpdateProvider(type = SqlProviderAdapter::class, method = "update")
    fun update(updateStatement: UpdateStatementProvider?): Int
}
```

But it doesn't work. If I trying awtowired FooMapper in java or kotlin class aplication failed on start with message like: can't find bean FooMapper. If I commented my autowired attemption, application starts, but when i check spring-bean-list i see that bean FooMapper doesn't exists.

How to convert my java mapper to Konlin?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is a simple example of of using MyBatis+Spring in Kotlin here: https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-dynamic-sql/tree/master/src/test/kotlin/examples/kotlin/mybatis3/column/comparison. Perhaps you need to add a @MapperScan annotation on a configuration class.

Comment: Have you found out the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was how the "idea" created folders.
When I manually created the correct folder structure that my mapper search configuration was configured for, then everything worked